# How to close zenity window by press on Cancel button?

Tags: linux, zenity

I have until loop and I can't get it how to break the loop when I click Cancel button? My until loop looks like this:

```
until [[ "$VAR" == "End" && **<second cond. for cancel>**  ]]; do
...
```

The problem is if I want to close the window I have to click on the red cross. If I want to do this with the "cancel" button, the window does not respond to it.

Tried to find the return value information after clicking cancel, and do an expression for that.

I wonder what the condition should be for it to work properly instead `<second cond. for cancel>`

SOLUTION: as someone said, `<secound cond. for cancel>` should be `$? == 1`. It works fine now.

Comment: Thanks for keeping the second condition classified. However, I have a feeling you need `||` not `&&`.

Comment: Or you might try `... ]] && [[ second cond. ... `.

Comment: I mean, I don't know what condition for cancel button should i use. I think that cancel button return exit $? value but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you update the question to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? At least show us how you're calling zenity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zenity exits with an exitcode of `1` if you press the cancel button (or close the dialog window, or press `<Escape>`). You could write something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

rc=0
until [[ $VAR == "End" || $rc == 1 ]]; do
    VAR=$(
        zenity --entry --text "Choose an action"
    )

    rc=$?
done
```

This loop will exit if you enter `End` in the text field, or if you press the `Cancel` button.